# Getting to Terelj National Park from Ulaanbaatar, Mongolia

Tags: transportation, mongolia, ulan-bator, national-parks

I have one day left in Mongolia, and would love to get to Gorkhi-Terelj / Terelj National Park for the day.  However, the only info I can find on getting there is on:

http://wikitravel.org/en/Gorkhi-Terelj_National_Park
[image]
Which states there is a bus at 4pm there, and two buses back (8am and 7pm).

This seems odd as there MUST be a demand for day-trippers.  Can anyone help out with info on alternate buses for getting there?

Comment: I always forget to ask - Are you on vacation? Or it is your job? How do you make money for this?

Comment: Last day today, I fly back to London in the morning ;)  Was on a long break, shall we say.  Have been working as a software contractor in London, but most of my cash goes into saving for travel - I enjoy it so much!

Comment: @Mark Mayo, and? did you make it to Terelj?

Comment: Sadly no, stomach bug and pulled muscle meant I decided against heading out there, but I hope to return next year and will be using the info then :)

Comment: Did you manage to go there in 2012?

Comment: @AndrewGrimm heh, no, moved to Canada instead. How plans change :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is a bus going from UB to Terelj.

If I remember correctly, it runs once every 2 hours? (at least several times a day). We got our info in one of the bars/cafes that is run by an expat. <strike>(I don't remember the name , it is a cafe that kinda stands out. lots of wood, it somewhat resembles a mountian hut. They organise tracks and stuff.)</strike> the place is called [Chez Bernard Café](http://www.chez-bernard.com/)

The bus leaves somewhere from the main street, and drops you off at the village at the south of Terelj Nation Park.